# Search for word in text file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this text file:

```
MemTotal,5,2016-07-30 12:02:33,781
model name,3,2016-07-30 13:37:59,074
model,3,2016-07-30 15:39:59,075
```

I need to find the line with the model.

My code:

```
term = "model"
file = open('file.txt')
for line in file:
    line.strip().split('/n')
    if term in line:
        print line
file.close()
```

This is the output:

```
model name,3,2016-07-30 13:37:59,074
model,3,2016-07-30 15:39:59,075
```

I need only this line as output:

```
 model,3,2016-07-30 15:39:59,075
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `term = "model,"` anyway it depends whether it's a generic case or specific one

Comment: `line.strip().split('/n')` doesn't do anything. `strip` and `split` don't work in-place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the line:

```
if term in line:
```

with line :

```
if line.startswith('model,'):
```

Comment: Just a small qustion. The guy says that he needs to find `model` in  the line. What if it's in between? Then your code fails

Comment: @sameerasy, based on the example data given by the OP, this is a correct answer.

Comment: yes , if its not in the beginning it will fail. But based on the sample data provided it seems this is some log file where it always start like this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your file contains. Your example is quite light, but I see a few immediate solutions that don't change your code too much :

1. Replace `term = 'model'` by `term = 'model,'` and this will only show the line you want.
2. Use some additional criteria, like *"must not contain `'name'`"*:

Like this:

```
term = 'model'
to_avoid = 'name'
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().split('/n')
        if term in line and to_avoid not in line:
            print line
```

**Additional remarks**

- You could use [`startswith('somechars')`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm) to check for some characters at the beginning of a string
- You need to assign the result of `strip()` and `split(\n)` in your variable, otherwise nothing happens.
- It's also better to use the keyword `with` instead of opening/closing files
- In general, I think you'd be better served with regular expressions for that type of thing you're doing. However, as pointed out by Nander Speerstra's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695194/serach-for-word-in-text-file-in-python/38695388?noredirect=1#comment64769667_38695388), this could be dangerous.

Comment: Good explanation of the `line = line.strip()` line and the use of `with`. But [**do not use regexes when unnecessary**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/113243/239397).

Answer (score 1):

You can split the line by `,` and check for the first field:

```
term = "model"
file = open('file.txt')
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split(',')  # <--- 
    if term == line[0]:             # <--- You can also stay with "if term in line:" if you doesn't care which field the "model" is. 
        print line
file.close()
```